# How can I make this return, return a number and not one function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, return

I am currently working on one new card game. I have one array full of numbers. I also have one object with a lot of functions, everytime I run mij object function it returns one function and not the first number from the array can anyone please help me?

Array: (Yeah a very complicated way to create one array with 4 times every numer between 1 and 10)

```
var cardDatabase = createDeck([].concat.apply([], new Array(10).fill().map((_, k) => new Array(4).fill(k + 1))))
```

Object + function:

```
function createDeck (array) {
  var cardDatabase = array

  return {
    peek: function () {
      return cardDatabase[cardDatabase.length - 1]
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: You are probably doing .peek instead of .peek()

Comment: to clarify on @juvian 's comment, because `.peek` is a property that is a function object, accessing `.peek` will return the function itself. However, *calling* the function by using `.peek()` will actually return the result of the function.

Comment: @juvian was right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var createDeck = function () {
    this.cardDatabase = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    this.peek = function () {
        return this.cardDatabase[this.cardDatabase.length - 1];
    };
    return this;
}
```

and `(new createDeck).peek();`

Comment: A constructor function should have a capitalised name and doesn't need to `return this`. Also, use the prototype for the `peek` method.